# How to prove (¬¬x→¬¬y) ⊢ (x→y)?

Tags: logic, proof-writing, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

How to prove (¬¬X→¬¬Y) ⊢ (X→Y) ?

What I've done:

1. [~X] `¬¬X→¬¬Y` implication exclusion
2. [Y]  `¬Y` **AND** introduction
3. `¬Y AND Y`
4. `[~~X]` DNE
5. `X` implication inclusion using the assumption of line 2
6. `Y→X`

Comment: What is "implication exlusion"?

Comment: It's modus ponens, right? When we have `A -> B` and the assumption that `A` is true, then we can derive `B`. I tried to do a similar thing here, but I ended up with  `~Y` because I assumed  `~X`.

Comment: Then (A) you mean "implication elimination", and you are putting the justification on the wrong line, and (B) you do not have the implication and *matching* antecedent to infer the *matching* consequent. $\neg X$ and $\neg\neg X\to\neg\neg Y$ will not entail $\neg Y$ by "implication elimination".

Comment: Also, your target is to derive $X\to Y$, and not $Y\to X$.  So your first assumption should be $X$.

Comment: What rules do you have?  There are soooooooo many different proof systems all with small (and not so small) differences in exactly what rules you do or do not have and how exactly they are defined.

Comment: DNE, DNI, MP, Reductio ad absurdum, disjunction and conjunction inclusion/exclusion @Bram28

Comment: @Jimmy How exactly is Reductio ad absurdum defined? Again, I have seen probably close to s dozen formulations of that very same idea. And for the kind of formal proof you are asked to do, that matters! Never hear of inclusion/exclusion rules for fisjunction and conjunction (see? Another formulation yet!), but for this problem they likely are kit needed. But the reductio  ad absurdum will be super important!

Comment: You assume that `C` is true. From that, you derive the `X and ¬X` , which is not possible to be. Because of that, you have `¬C`.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a lot of things right, but much is in the wrong place.

Foremost: Justifications belong on the line of the statement they are being used to derive (it also helps to reference the lines being used for that derivation).

Also, place assumptions on their own lines.  Some form of indentation to show where assumptions are raised and discharged is helpful too.

Finally there's the order of your derivations.

Your *actual* target is to derive $X\to Y$ (not $Y\to X$).  So the first assumption needs to be $X$, with the aim of $Y$, so that you may then use "Implication Inclusion" (more commonly known as "Conditional Introduction") to get what you want to get.

Working backwards from there, you know that "Double Negation Elimination" is used to do what it says.  However, since you are actually aiming for $Y$ you will first need to obtain $\neg\neg Y$.

You know to use "Implication Exclusion" (more commonly known as "Conditional Elimination") but aren't matching the form.  Since you have $\neg\neg X\to\neg\neg Y$ as the premise, you may use it with $\neg\neg X$ to derive $\neg\neg Y$ by this rule.  And since that is what you seek to do, you will first need to obtain $\neg\neg X$.

You know that you can do this by assuming a negation and deriving a contradiction.    That negation is $\neg X$, and it contradicts the $X$ you have previously assumed.

Just put it back together.

Comment: I'm a bit confused with "`And since that is what you seek to do, you will first need to obtain ¬¬.`". You mean "`¬¬Y`" here, right?

Comment: I'm assuming that because in the previous paragraph you wrote "`However, since you are actually aiming for  you will first need to obtain ¬¬.`"

Comment: You have $\neg\neg X\to\neg\neg Y$ and wish to derive $\neg\neg Y$ from it by "Implication Exclusion".  You will need to have $\neg\neg X$ to do so, @jimmy .  So first derive $\neg\neg X$ by other means.

Answer (score 0):

So that would become:

1. [~Y] `¬¬X→¬¬Y` implication exclusion
2. [X]  `¬X` **AND** introduction
3. `¬X AND X`
4. `[~~Y]` DNE
5. `Y` implication inclusion using the assumption of line 2
6. `X→Y`

Comment: No. But it is slightly better. Keep working on it.